# Wedge product of matrix is equal to the product of wedge matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, exterior-algebra

Let $A, B:X : \to GL(d, \mathbb{R})$ be continuous function over a compact metric space. Is true that $$A^{\wedge t}(x) B^{\wedge t}(y)=(A(x)B(y))^{\wedge t}$$
for any $x, y \in X$?

You can find helpful information about the wedge product [here](https://math.fandom.com/wiki/Wedge_product).

Comment: the link you provide only gives information on the wedge product in $\mathbb R^3$. How to define it for elements of $GL(d,\mathbb R)?$. Moreover, why are you considering the a continuous function from $X$? it seems to me to be the statement about two matrices, but maybe I am missing something

Comment: If I understand your notation correctly, doesn't this follow immediately from $$A(v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_k) = Av_1 \wedge \dots \wedge Av_k?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $X$ is a distraction, this is just a statement about matrices. Formally, taking the [exterior power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Exterior_power) $V \mapsto \Lambda^k(V)$ is a [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor), meaning that it satisfies the property that if $f : V \to W, g : U \to V$ are linear maps then $\Lambda^k(fg) = \Lambda^k(f) \Lambda^k(g)$. This follows from the definition of the exterior power in terms of universal properties, which says that $\Lambda^k(V)$ is the universal recipient of an alternating multilinear map from $V^k$.

Comment: I do not recommend using the antisymmetrization definition of the wedge product; it's awful to calculate with and very annoying to e.g. prove associativity. The definition in terms of taking a quotient, rather than a subspace, of the tensor power $V^{\otimes k}$ is much cleaner and easier to work with.